# Symfony 2 controller loses container when forwarded to another controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller that forwards the whole request to another controller.
The first controller is `Version1Controller`, and `$this->controller` is not null, giving me access to services. It forwards the request to `GetUserTrialsController` defined in services as `controller.get_user_trials`. In the second controller `$this->container` is null. How come symfony loses it half way through? Is there any way to pass the container around?

Below is the code to demonstrate the behaviour

services.yml

```
services:
    controller.get_user_trials:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\GetUserTrialsController
```

Version1Controller.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Version1Controller extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump("V1Controller " . json_encode(is_null($this->container)));
        return $this->forward("controller.get_user_trials:indexAction");
    }
}
```

GetUserTrials.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class GetUserTrialsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump("GetUserTrials " . json_encode(is_null($this->container)));
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

The output:

```
string(18) "V1Controller false"
string(13) "GetUserTrials true"
abc
```

Comment: Second controller is service, so you must inject container to that service.

Comment: I would expect $this->forward to do that for me? The function does this -         return $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST); It seems to me as if it is initialing a new request and does exactly the same thing it did for original? And that would include setting the service container

Comment: When the controller is created in `App:Controller:Action` format then the container is injected by the framework, otherwise you have to do it yourself. If you want it to be a service you have to arrange for the container to be injected (via a listener or the service definition).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This explains what my problem was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to amplify a bit on what @qooplmao has said.  It is important to understand that there are two distinct ways to instantiate a controller.

The most common way is is by specifying a three part controller string.  Something like MyBundle:MyController:my.  When a string like this is encountered the routing system determines the controller class, instantiates a new object and then calls setContainer to inject the container.

You can however define a controller as a service by using a string with only two parts.  When you do this the routing system simply pulls the object from the container with no additional processing.  It's entirely possible that your controller does not need the container at all so there is no point in injecting it.

In your case, just add a call to setContainer in your service definition.

```
services:
  controller.get_user_trials:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\GetUserTrialsController
    calls: [[setContainer, ['@service_container']]]
```

And all will be well.  Or don't define your controller as a service and just use:

```
$this->forward("AppBundle:GetUserTrials:index");
```

I happen to like defining controllers as services but the standard approach works fine for most cases.

Comment: Thank you for summarising comment, this is much more clear now. I guess I will move away from using controllers as services for now until i strip them so that they don't extend SF2 Controller base class anymore

Comment: Your choice of course.  I define my controllers as services and inject the specific dependencies they need such as repositories.  I never pull stuff from the container in my action methods.  I still use the base framework class to take advantage of the standard helper functions.  Take a look at the FOSUserBundle controllers as an example of how NOT to define controllers as services.